# Manipulate image source based on variable

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get this to work: 
I've got string variable in a file called `test.js`. Depending on some values the file is created by a php script and it says something like: `var test = 'up'` or: var `test = 'down'`.

Now, I would like display a certain image on my website depending on the value of `var test`. So in my html code I add this to the header:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
```

Then in the body I write:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

    function Test(){
        if (test == 'up'){
            document.getElementById("test").src = '/img/arrows/arrow_up.png';
        }
        else if (test == 'down'){
            document.getElementById("test").src = '/img/arrows/arrow_down.png'; 
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("test").src = '/img/arrows/arrow_neutral.png';
        }
    }
</script>
```

And I add in the image with:

```
<img id="test" src="" class="test">
```

However, nothing is displayed on the page. Can someone help me out?

Comment: did you run `Test()` anywhere?

Comment: Please create a working snippet demonstrating your issue. Are you calling `Test` anywhere?

Comment: You generally shouldn't dynamically create JS on the fly. It would be more elegant to use  HTML data-* attributes, read them in JS, or <script type="application/json"></script>, read and parse from JS.

Comment: Well, guess I was still asleep... Thank you guys nonetheless!

Comment: Personally I'd use css-classes and define your images there, if it just a "background image" which doesn't have to flow with text. Just switch classes from within javascript!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call `Test()` somewhere, the code below executes it, when the page is fully loaded, so the other `.js` file has executed(`test` has been set) and the `<img>` is on the page.

```js
var test = 'down';

function Test() {
  if (test == 'up') {
    document.getElementById("test").src = '/img/arrows/arrow_up.png';
  } else if (test == 'down') {
    document.getElementById("test").src = '/img/arrows/arrow_down.png';
  } else {
    document.getElementById("test").src = '/img/arrows/arrow_neutral.png';
  }
}

window.onload = function() {
  Test()
};
```

```html
<img id="test" src="" class="test">
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, try to put manually a src to see if the src is correct :

```
  <img id="test" src="/img/arrows/arrow_up.png" class="test">
```

If it works, you should call your Test() function somewhere :

```
 window.onload = function() {
   Test();
 };
```

To make simplier, you can use JQuery (not obligatory) :

You should add jquery reference to your html page (depending on your scripts folder, the link can change) :

```
 <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
```

And you can change your Test() methode on this :

```
  function Test(){
    debugger;
    if (test == 'up'){
        $("#test").attr("src", '/img/arrows/arrow_up.png');
    }
    else if (test == 'down'){
        $("#test").attr("src", '/img/arrows/arrow_down.png'); 
    }
    else {
        $("#test").attr("src", '/img/arrows/arrow_neutral.png');
    }
  }
```

Finally, to check if your test parameter is correct, you can put a debugger in order to debug your code in any browser.
If you open the developper tools of your browser, (by pressing on F12 on the browser) you can debug your code. The code will hit the debugger keyword.

Comment: why exactly does he need jQuery?

Comment: To make simplier. Not an obligation. I said to make simple. I changed my comment.

Comment: I don't want to start a fight about jQuery here, but there is no reason why anyone would need it in this example

Comment: Ok, so we don't fight. I just said that it is an option, you can use or not. But for this exemple or for another, JQuery is very usefull. I think every frontend developper should know a little about JQuery. You can take this like a little advice for him.

Comment: Yes I absolutly agree, that it can be useful and is a thing good to know, but if you put a jQuery answer to a pure JS question other people who seacrh for the same question and don't want to use jQuery can't use your answer